# .each() loop wait for another loop to finish before starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have two main loops for `posts` and `comments`. However the comments don't display, presumably because the post ID is not on the DOM yet (?).

```
$.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){

    //posts 

    $.each(data.freshposts, function(id, post) {
        // set variables and append divs to document
        var id = post.id;
        ...
    });

    // comments attached to each post

    $.each(data.freshcomments, function(id, commentList) {
        $.each(commentList, function(index, c) {
            // set variables and append comments to each post div
            var postid = c.postid; // this is the same as post.id (linked)
            ...

            var full = "<div> ... </div>";

            $('#comment-block'+postid).append(full); // comment-block+postid is attached with each post div, so it tells the comment which div it should be appended to.
        })
    });
});
```

Does not display comments ^

If I wrap the `$.each` loop for the comments in a `setTimeOut(function(){},1)`, the comments are able to be displayed - I suppose it needs to wait 1 millisecond before the loop can commence? However this doesn't seem like a good/fool-proof way to ensure this.

```
setTimeOut(function(){
    $.each(data.freshcomments, function(id, commentList) {
        ...
    })
},1)
```

Displays comments ^

Comment: Your code should work fine as it is. Are there any async methods being used within your first `$.each` block?

Comment: What is an async method?

Comment: search jquery official docs for `promise`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this after a few hours of work.

I made two functions, `getPosts()` and `appendComments()`. I used the promise method:

```
function getPosts(){

    var deferred = new $.Deferred(); // new deferred

    $.getJSON('fresh_posts.php',function(data){
        global_save_json = data.freshcomments;
        var howManyPosts = Object.keys(data.freshposts).length; // how many posts there are (object length)
        var arrayCount = 0;
        $.each(data.freshposts, function(id, post) {

// closing tags for above

return deferred.promise();

}
```

I had an async method (just learned what that was) to check if the image was designed for retina displays within `getPosts`.

```
if (retina === "true") {

    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {

        var retina_width = this.width/2;
        var post = '...';
        $('.main').append(post);
        arrayCount++; // for each post add +1 to arrayCount
        if  (arrayCount == howManyPosts) { // if last post
            deferred.resolve();
        }
    }
  img.src = image;

  } else {
  ...
```

I then did

`getPosts().then(appendComments);`

after closing tag of the function `getPosts`. So basically even though the function finishes, it still waits for the async method to also finish within that function before the function `getComments` is called. That way the post id's will exist on the document for the comments to be appended to.

`appendComments` looks like this:

```
function appendComments(){

    if (global_save_json != null){
        $.each(global_save_json, function(id, commentList) {
        $.each(commentList, function(index, c) {
```